# Rails 4, need to reload the page to appear facebook social plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a show page with articles, where people can comment and share using facebook. The problem is that the facebook comments and share button only appears after the second time we reload the page! Anyone know how to solve this issue? Here is my code:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<%= request.original_url %>" data-type="button"></div>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%= request.original_url %>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

And in the layout I have this code:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=255630284624962&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: How do you init the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Comment: like they are showing in the facebook's developer page! I will update the question with the code. Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the divs don't exists on the page when the Facebook Javascript SDK is loaded.

Comment: But why the plugin appear after reload the page? I am new on rails and don't have much experience...

Comment: My guess would be if you dynamically add then there is some race condition.

Comment: Put them in a document.load and they still don't show up until a refresh.  Many questions on SO on this - most unanswered or reference solutions which don't work for my sites.